Unable to connect to external display (22.04.4 LTS on Lenovo t480)
I’m running 22.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo t480 and had been using a Dell external display without issue until I attempted to configure the Intel drivers using information on this page: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005520/graphics.html
Somehow I’ve lost the ability to use the external display and am lost on how best to proceed.Here are the basics from neofetch --stdout:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: 20L50011US ThinkPad T480 
Kernel: 6.5.0-45-generic 
Uptime: 16 mins 
Packages: 2620 (dpkg), 68 (brew), 21 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-8350U (8) @ 3.600GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 3716MiB / 31851MiB

Here's the output from cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -E "\(EE\)":
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    17.283] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    17.283] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    17.284] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    17.284] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.284] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.

Here's the relevant output from sudo update-pciids && lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
3c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983

Any guidance is appreciated.

OK, it appears the mistake was mine in not noticing that the Arc driver does NOT support my processor: Intel Core i5-8350U, which is 8th generation.
The other mistake I made was that rather than run the scripts provided in the post I manually performed each command thinking I was being more careful.
As a result, I'm currently looking at which of these commands I need to manually undo.

Per my comment, I determined that I had erroneously followed the Intel Arc driver installation despite my processor not being supported. Once I removed the erroneously installed packages with the following command and rebooted, the external display was functional again: sudo apt remove intel-fw-gpu intel-i915-dkms xpu-smi
